# Landscape question for provisioning

Tags: landscape

I am new to the Landscape solution and I can't really find 100% accurate information.

Is Landscape providing build in solution for bare-metal (laptops) provisioning or it relies on some external solution for those kind of tasks?

Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Landscape mostly does remote package management, script execution and some monitoring.

It will not help you with installing Ubuntu on machines, if that's what you're looking for. That would be better served by MaaS, or by making a custom ISO.

What Landscape can do is allow you to trigger installation of packages, sets of packages and control the updates of those packages once those computers are set up and have a configured Landscape client installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you have any knowledge or heard about Maas co-operating with Landscape?